# Cannot install yum-utils to resolve broken installation due to conflict

Tags: linux, yum

I am trying to install yum-utils package to resolve a broken installation, but it fails due to a conflict:

```
sudo yum install yum-utils --skip-broken
```

returns

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package yum-utils.noarch 0:1.1.30-6.11.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: yum-utils-1.1.30-6.11.amzn1.noarch conflicts system-release <= 2011.09-1.33
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
yum-utils-1.1.30-6.11.amzn1.noarch from amzn-updates
```

I am finding myself in a catch-22 situation and I don't know how to resolve it. Cannot install any package with yum because of a broken installation (it recommends to run yum-complete-transaction which is in yum-utils), but installing yum-utils also fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I ran into the same problem - yum bombed out and I couldn't install yum-complete-transaction.

In the end, what I did was copy /usr/sbin/yum-complete-transaction across from another Amazon instance, then ran it and after it finished the remaining transactions installed the 'yum-utils' package.

I know this is probably not the 'most correct' method to fix it, but it worked and quite frankly, if it's stupid but worked, it's not stupid :)